# Migrating questions from unregistered users should be impossible

Tags: feature-request, migration

I really appreciate the idea that one can almost fully use SE without registration; however this opportunity becomes totally screwed up when the Q is migrated.

An unexperienced user (who was told that he does not need registration!) is out of the blue faced with registering at two sites and hoping for automagical association system to work.   Moreover, he is left on his own since there are no automatic tips what to do and moderators on neither site can do nothing but squeezing instructions into comments in mostly inadequate places.

I think it would be much better if migrating was impossible in this case and thus this user would have just saw a closed question and an instruction to move to proper site and ask there again. (It seems like an unfriendly additional work, but on a bright side it gives an occasion to adjust the contents to the target site, which is often required. Moreover unregistered users frequently do this on their own when they see comments suggesting the Q belongs somewhere else.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the benefit.

In both cases:

1. The user gets their question closed and (probably) no help
2. The user has to go to another site for help

I don't think any confusion is spared since the user still needs to go to the other site, register, and associate their accounts if they want that to happen.  The only difference is that they also have to repost the question.

I could see a message prompt saying "Hey, you'll need to register in order to regain control of the migrated question" being useful, though.

Comment: Not at all -- user abandons account on A, goes to B and operates as unregistered there. The benefit is huge -- no dangling "gray-user" questions, answers instead of comments, lost reputation and problems with merging users.

Comment: @mbq If the user operates as unregistered user, then he doesn't have any control over the question that has been migrated; if he asks the same question as unregistered user, then the new question will be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Precisely; yet there are two options to fix it -- either write a good system to migrate temporal cookie (unrealistic) or to ban such migrations.